# Request returns partial page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse data of a website that loads when user scroll. There is a finite number of element that can appears while scrolling, but using this only gives the first part (25 out of 112):

```
url = "http://url/to/website"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

How can I tell `request` to "scroll" before returning the html?

EDIT : apparently request don't do that, what solution can I use in Python?

Comment: You can probably mimic what happens when you scroll through http requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing you should know is how serverlet works.

Usually, `onScroll` or `onClick` or any other event will trigger `AJAX request` to the server. And the client side javascript will render those return (JSON/XML...) So the only thing you should do is to repeat those AJAX request to the same server to get those data.

For example, the action in browser will like below:

```
1. Enter url on browser   
> [HTTP GET REQUEST] http://url/to/website

2. Scroll on the page
> [AJAX GET] http://url/to/website/1
> [javascript on front-end will process those data]

3. Then, keeping scrolling on the page
> [AJAX GET] http://url/to/website/2
> [javascript on front-end will process those data]

4. ... (and so on)
```

---

**Q. How to use python to get those data?**

A. One simple way is using `browser > inspect > network_tab` to find what AJAX request you send when you scroll in that page. And repeat those AJAX request with correspond header by python.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The question is based on a misunderstanding of what requests does; it loads the content of the page only. Endless scrolling is powered by Javascript, which requests won't do anything with.

You'd need some browser automation tools like Selenium to do this; or find out what Ajax endpoint the scrolling JS is using and load that directly.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit afraid of that. I updated my question to find a concrete solution